# Can you do list slicing in the Jac language?

Tags: jaseci

As the title suggests, is there a way to slice a list in Jac? something like,

```
short_list = original_list[3:5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep,

Try running this in Jaseci:

```
walker init {
    a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    report a[4:7];
}
```